# как реализовать темную тему на сайте по типу как youtube?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, frontend, youtube

Нужно сделать переключатель на ночной режим как youtube, это можно сделать только на фронтенде ? через localstorage ?

P.S.: гугл не помог с ответом.

Comment: на youtube тегу `html` устанавливается атрибут `dark='true'`. В стилях прописаны правила `html[dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope), [dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope){...}` и `[dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) *:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope){...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

на youtube тегу `html` устанавливается атрибут `dark='true'`.

В стилях прописаны правила:

```
html[dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope), [dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope){...}
```

и

```
[dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) *:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope){...}
```

Где хранить данные - в localstorage или cookie или еще как-то зависит напрямую от Вашего способа реализации и только.

---

Пример на `div`(для `html` идентично, во встроенном фиддле не показать):

```js
$(".change").on("click", function() {
  if (!$(".content").attr("dark")) {
    $(".content").attr("dark", "true");
  } else {
    $(".content").removeAttr("dark");

  }
})
```

```css
html[dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope),
[dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) {
  background-color: #000;
}

[dark]:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) *:not([style-scope]):not(.style-scope) {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div>какой-то контент</div>
  <button type="btn" class="change">изменить тему</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую.